# Error performing transaction, Every document read in a transaction must also be written., null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am receiving this error when querying a Firestore database using Flutter.

> E/flutter (17558): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing transaction, Every document read in a transaction must also be written., null)

```
Future getFavorites(String uid) {
  DocumentReference favoritesReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid);
  List favoritesList = [];

  return Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
    DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(favoritesReference);
    var length;
    if (postSnapshot.exists) {
      length = postSnapshot.data['favorites'].length;
    }

    print(length);
  });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should update your client libraries to the latest versions.

Comment: Everything is up-to-date. Android Studio, Flutter plugin, Dependencies - All latest versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not writing your document. Each document read in the transaction should be written. Then, you can add a `set()`, `update()` or `delete()` that corresponds to each of the document reads.

If you don't need to write back to `favoritesReference`, then read it before the transaction rather than inside the transaction.